# Handler callback not receiving message

Tags: android

So I call an AsyncTask in my MainActivity. Before sending a handler message back in the AsyncTask (onPostExecute), I call another activity via intent in MainActivity. But when I try to send the message back, I can't receive it by either activity (handler callback interface). I would like to receive this message in the MainActivity.

FYI when I remove the call to the second activity, the message is received as expected.

Any hints on how to achieve this?

```
//mainactivity oncreate()
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     ...
     Handler handler = new Handler(this);
     new MyAsyncTask(handler).execute();
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondaryActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     ...
}

//async
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String >
{
     private Handler handler;

     public UpdateTask(Handler handler)
     {
          this.handler = handler;
     }
     ...
     protected void onPostExecute(TmiResponse result)
     {
         handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, Constants.MSG_DONE, result));
     }
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
{
     //no messages received here
}
```

Comment: how are you creating your handler reference?

Comment: in the constructor of my asynctask
edit: code change

Comment: is your handleMessage an overridden method?

Comment: yes, i'll edit the code here

Comment: did you try to debug your code?